# How can I get the referrer URL in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-reactive, spring-boot-2, spring5

How can I get the referrer URL in Spring Webflux? 
I tried to look into the header attributes in `ServerWebExchange exchange` object but could not found the same.
Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Did you try just using `@RequestHeader`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just obtain it as a normal header - it doesn't really matter what mechanism you use to do this, since they all have header access.

> I tried to look into the header attributes in `ServerWebExchange`

If you want it on `ServerWebExchange`, you can definitely obtain it via the following:

```
serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("referer");
```

If you want it as a parameter to a normal REST mapping, you can just use `@RequestHeader`:

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Mono<String> greeting(@RequestHeader("referer") Optional<String> referer) {
    //...
}
```

Or if you're using a `ServerRequest`:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> greeting(ServerRequest request) {
    String referer = request.headers().firstHeader("referer");
    //...
}
```